# JSON encoding returns array of objects, how to access them?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

**AJAX CALL**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: './php/testing/notification-regrab.php',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'text/json',
    error: function (result) {
      alert("ERROR124");
    },
    success: function (result) {
      var data = $.parseJSON(result);
      console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**RESULT WITHOUT json.parse**

```
{"notes":{"0":{"id":"3","sender":"0000000011","sendee":"0000000001","sent":"2015-03-11 00:00:00","is_read":"0","type":"14","ix_msg":"You have recived a response to your group invitation!","sender_fname":"mot","sender_lname":"mot","sender_username":"mot","msg":"Sure, I will join the project group.","target":"1","skill_list":null,"resource_list":null,"response":"1","request_type":null,"request_string":null,"rating":null},"1":{"id":"4","sender":"0000000011","sendee":"0000000001","sent":"2015-03-19 00:00:00","is_read":"0","type":"1","ix_msg":"Hey, you recieved a message from mot","sender_fname":"mot","sender_lname":"mot","sender_username":"mot","msg":"Hey, This is a messgae sent to tom from mot","target":"0","skill_list":null,"resource_list":null,"response":null,"request_type":null,"request_string":null,"rating":null},"2":{"id":"5","sender":"0000000011","sendee":"0000000001","sent":"2015-03-19 04:13:30","is_read":"0","type":"1","ix_msg":"You have recieved a message from mot.","sender_fname":"mot","sender_lname":"mot","sender_username":"mot","msg":"Hey there friend.","target":null,"skill_list":null,"resource_list":null,"response":null,"request_type":null,"request_string":null,"rating":null}}}
```

**RESULT WITH json.parse (I opened the first result for Object 0, so you can see what it holds)**

```
Object {notes: Object}
notes: Object
  0: Object
     id: "3"
     is_read: "0"
     ix_msg: "You have recived a response to your group invitation!"
     msg: "Sure, I will join the project group."
     rating: null
     request_string: null
     request_type: null
     resource_list: null
     response: "1"
     sendee: "0000000001"
     sender: "0000000011"
     sender_fname: "mot"
     sender_lname: "mot"
     sender_username: "mot"
     sent: "2015-03-11 00:00:00"
     skill_list: null
     target: "1"
     type: "14"
     __proto__: Object
  1: Object
  2: Object
  __proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

**This is the PHP array that makes up the above data:**

```
$arr = array(
    "id" => $row["id"],
    "sender" => $row["sender"],
    "sendee" => $row["sendee"],
    "type" => $row["type"],
    "posting" => $row["posting"],
    "msg" => $row["msg"],
    "sent" => $row["sent"],
    "read" => $row["read"],
);
```

**PROBLEM**
Okay, so I am trying to loop through each notification with jquery, but I first want to test how I can return a single notification object from this array of objects...

I want to do the following for example:

console.log(data[0].id);

Which should just return the string "3", since that is the first id in the first notification...

If I do the above, it says the follow error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

I have no idea how to read the json objects...

Please someone help me and tell me how to properly output the above data...

Comment: FYI: That's not an array of objects.

Comment: why is this getting upvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in the request change text/kaon with application/json also make sure the server returns the proper header.

The php part should be something like: 
    $note = array("id" => 123, "name" => "some name")

```
$notes = array();
$notes[] = $note;
```

The jQuery part is easy:
    $.each(notes, function(i, note) {
    console.log(note.name);
    });

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out....

I had this before, but I forgot to use parseJSON...

console.log(data.notes[0].id);

Thanks